# Эмуляция действий пользователя на сайте

Tags: webbrowser, эмулятор

Требуется эмулировать активность пользователя. Пробовал делать это с помощью casperjs, но в метрике от яндекса вебвизор так пользователя и не видит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобных программ много, из того, что на слуху - [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

В википедии есть [таблица сравнения](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_testing_tools) некоторых инструментов для веб-тестирования.

Comment: Я нашел всего несколько решений, а именно phantomjs, casperjs (который по сути обертка для phantomjs), selenium.
Самый быстрый для старта оказался каспер.
Какие программы еще существуют?

Comment: Добавил в ответ еще ссылку.